# telegram bot that can handle multiple users at the same time - python

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm trying to create a telegram bot using ""python-telegram-bot"" that help user to reset some passwords in the below steps: 
user send "/start" to start the bot 
bot replies with "enter username"
user enters their username
bot asks for user id
after verfication
bot asks user to enter his pass
and change the password for this user,
HOWEVER

the bot cannot handle multiple users at the same time, means, if user enters his name "A" and then enter his user id, if another user "B" started the bot and entered his name it will conflicts and ask user "A" for his id again..

how can i handle this

Comment: Any help here.?

Answer (score 0):

when you do an action to the downloader function:

```py
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.document, downloader))
```

Like this one, do another function inside `downloader`:

```py
def downloader(var,var):
    def again_def(var,var):
        return blabla
   
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=again_def,args=(var, var))
    t2.start()
    
if __name__ =="__main__":
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.document, downloader))
```